# panel not showing in service console for a particular record type

Tags: case, record-type, servicecloud, service-cloud-console

I have a specific Record type for case object. When I see the record of this type in service console, there is Suggested Articles panel which is not populated, while this is populated for all other Record types. Is there anything I need to do with Page layout??

What could be the issue with this. Kindly suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn on this side panel in the Page Layout associated with that Record type.  If you have 5 different Case page layouts, you would need to turn it on in all 5.
In setup, go to the Case Object,  Setup|Customize|Cases|Page Layouts. Then select the Page Layouts menu item, and select each page layout.
Then select the "Layout Properties" button and check the "Knowledge Sidebar" checkbox.

Comment: How do I do it?? I am hearing it first time. Though a learner in customization too. Please let me know

Comment: I am at the page layout associated with that Record Type. But I dont see any panel there. In which section I can see that

Comment: Updated my answer with additional direction.

Comment: No.. There is no such checkbox. 
I have followed all the steps you suggested and also the one in the link

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=console2_setup_knowledge.htm&language=en

I am a system admin. And I don see that chekcbox

Comment: Yes Yes !!! you were right.. I was not a Knowledge user so I was not able to see that checkbox. Thank you so much.